# Error while configuring Windows Server Appfabric for XML (as Caching Service configuration provider)

Tags: appfabric, data-caching

Error while configuring Windows Server Appfabric for XML (as Caching Service configuration provider) :-

System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: ErrorCode:SubStatus:Could not set permissions on configuration store : ErrorCode:SubStatus:Error occurred while configuring permissions on network share: Access is denied. Refer to the product documentation for manually configuring the store permissions. ---> Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode:SubStatus:Could not set permissions on configuration store : ErrorCode:SubStatus:Error occurred while configuring permissions on network share: Access is denied. Refer to the product documentation for manually configuring the store permissions. ---> Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode:SubStatus:Error occurred while configuring permissions on network share: Access is denied ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Configuration.NetworkShareManagement.NetworkShare.GetAccessControl(String server, String shareName)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Configuration.Commands.RegisterCacheHostCommand.SetNetworkSharePermissions(String serverName, String shareName, IdentityReference[] ids)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Configuration.Commands.RegisterCacheHostCommand.SetNetworkSharePermissions(String serverName, String shareName, IdentityReference[] ids)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Configuration.Commands.RegisterCacheHostCommand.SetNetworkSharePermissions(String velocityConfigPath, String account, String serviceHost)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Configuration.Commands.RegisterCacheHostCommand.SetConfigurationStorePermissions()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Configuration.Commands.RegisterCacheHostCommand.BeginProcessing()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TOutput](IEnumerable input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Configuration.DistributedCacheProxy.RegisterCacheHost(DistributedCacheSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Configuration.DistributedCacheNodePage.backgroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding a second machine for your cache? If so, [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/velocity/thread/2305d288-3beb-4786-b627-bd8b2d9be274) should give you the answer.

Basically, you either need to get a new Machine SID or remove your machine from the domain, and add it back in.